# Multiple Python Installations of the same python version on a single computer

Tags: python, installation, windows-installer

I want to install the new Python 2.7 on my Windows XP 32bit PC.

having CDO (thats OCD with initials sorted in alphabetical order) I want to install it multiple times on the same computer (to different TARGETDIRs).

how do i do that ? double clicking on the installer, or running msiexec multiple times did not work for me

Coincidentally, I noticed that the windows python installation does not ask me if I want to add a Start Menu option. I want my installations of python not to show up on the Start Menu. How do I do that?

be well

Comment: +1 for "CDO" ;) and its a fair question that I don't know the answer to.

Comment: It was all nice and easy right up until you said "Windows". Then it got hard as hell.

Comment: Why do you want to - if you have different libraries then virtualenv might be a better solution

Comment: As to Start Menu, can't you just delete the shortcut?

Comment: @Mark: I am creating an python-based application for clients. i dont want them to install python themselves. i dont know if they already have python on their computers. i want to install a separate version of python as part of my application installation. this version will be used only to run my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want multiple independent copies of Python 2.7 running on Windows. I assume that is so you can install just the packages you need for each project and not have different projects fighting over conflicting versions.

Try using virtualenv (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). You install Python once, then whenever you need a new copy you run virtualenv.py and it effectively gives you a clean environment with an `activate` script (`activate.bat` on Windows) that makes that environment the current one.

Having said all that, I've only used virtualenv on Linux so I don't know how well it works on Windows, but it certainly claims to work on Windows so give it a go.

*Edit:* For running Python scripts on machines without having to worry whether or not it is already there, the usual solution is to use py2exe (http://www.py2exe.org/). That bundles your application and all libraries together with Python in a single standalone file which can be run without any installation.

Comment: Ah, ok. My answer crossed with your comment about wanting to install on clients machines without affecting their existing Python. So my assumption was wrong.

Comment: unfortunately py2exe and its brethren dont play nice with some of the libraries im using (Chaco, Traits etc. due to some very funky import work these libraries perform) so i havent been able to create an executable. Thus i resort to a python installation

Answer (score 0):

Based on one of your comments, it looks like you don't actually need to *install* it, you just need it on the computer so your program can run. In that case you can take a page from Dropbox's book and include the interpreter, DLL, and standard library in one of your directories, and just use it from there.

Comment: Technically speaking - using py2exe is *also* a little hacking - it's just an automated process.

Comment: Unfortunately, just copying the files (without registering the python27.dll and dlls of other python libraries) wont work. so I guess i need to run the installation somehow